# How to eliminate both head and tail recursion

Tags: recursion

I have code like this.

```
void someFn(arguments...)
{
    if (! condition)
        return;

    someFn(arguments1...);
    doSomeWork(arguments);
    someFn(arguments2...);
}
```

I just want to know if there is any genric way to eliminate both head and tail recursion.

Comment: Add the language tag.

Comment: It's not possible unless you can remove the need. You can move the stack to avoid stack overflow but you'll still have a custom growing stack and it will because of that still be (emulated) recursion.

Comment: It's okay to have a stack. I just want to remove the recursive call.